# Select every nth row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Been a while since I did some SQL, so I have been given some to look at and try to make more efficient, with a table that has millions of rows.

And I want to select every 100,000th sequenceid (not row, so row_number() is not being used) into a tempory table, at the moment it is doing this, now granted it takes about 15 seconds, but is there a more efficient and quicker way?

```
declare @temp table(id int, date datetime)
declare @loop int, @max int, @min int
select @min = min(id) from tableA
select @max = max(id) from tableA
set @loop = @min + 100000

while (@loop < @max)
begin
  insert into @temp
  select id, date from tableA where id = @loop
  set @loop = @loop + 100000
end
```

Comment: Modulus (%) is probably the way to go.  Assuming that your "id" is sequential.  Something like "select id, date from tableA where id % 100000 = 0"  Can't speak for how fast that would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Mod(%)

```
insert into @temp
select id, date from tableA 
where 
  (id - @min) % 100000= 0 AND
  id > @min -- to get the same logic as in your question
```

EDIT:

It may be more effective to calculate all values for id in your situation:

```
;WITH cte as
(
  SELECT @min + 100000 id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 100000+ id
  FROM cte
  WHERE id  <= max(id) - 100000
)
INSERT @temp
SELECT id, date 
FROM tableA a
JOIN
cte on cte.id = a.id
OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note that SQL Server 2014 introduced a native T-SQL [MOD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped thanks, I didn't know that. Still running SQL Server 2008

Comment: That took in excess of 5 minutes to complete compared to the 15 seconds for the while loop, I am assuming the modulo is a bit of an overhead? If it is performing calculations on id's that run into millions.

Comment: great thanks, works a treat.  And embarrassingly the reason things were so slow was that someone was restoring databases on the server!